# Spring Boot Value always uses default value

Tags: spring-boot

I've got a spring boot application, which was migrated from plain spring.
So I'm also migrating the XML configurations to java based configurations. At the moment XML configurations and java based configurations are mixed.

My problem ist, that values from property files are not used when I specify a default value:

```
 // does not work: myPropertyWithDefault is always default-value
 @Value("${my.property:default-value}")
 private String myPropertyWithDefault;


 // works
 @Value("${my.property}")
 private String myProperty;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

The issue is when there are XML configurations which use `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/my-values.properties" />` elements. These elements instantiate a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`, but `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` cannot handle the @Value annotions properly.

**Solution**

So my solution is to replace all `<context:property-placeholder/>` elements with `@PropertySource("classpath:/my-values.properties")` annotations.